# Issues with azure.identity when using federated credentials

Tags: python, azure, authentication, github, pytest

I'm running a GH actions pipeline which is configured to login Azure cli using federated credentials (and this works fine):

```
env:
  ARM_USE_OIDC: true

steps:
- name: az login
  uses: azure/login@v1
  with:
    client-id: ${{ env.ARM_CLIENT_ID }}
    tenant-id: ${{ env.ARM_TENANT_ID }}
    subscription-id: ${{ env.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
```

then I'm running pytest which does some python code, some TF runs, etc. plain Az Cli\TF calls using subprocess work, however when I'm using `AzureCliCredential` or `DefaultAzureCredential` calls to `get_token` fail with:

> Output: ERROR: AADSTS700024: Client assertion is not within
> its valid time range. Current time: 2023-12-19T07:20:31.3554289Z, assertion
> valid from 2023-12-19T05:59:24.0000000Z, expiry time of assertion
> 2023-12-19T06:04:24.0000000Z

The same code was working previously using certificate auth

EDIT: what was confusing me is the fact that the tokens I'm getting have proper lifetime, which doesnt match the error. what I'm thinking now is that the underlying OIDC token issued by Github has only 5 minutes of lifetime hence it doesnt matter if oAuth tokens have 1h lifetime

EDIT: related issues:
https://github.com/Azure/login/issues/372
https://github.com/Azure/login/issues/180

Comment: looks like the token expired after 5min and it tries to use the token later on (~1h20 later ?)

Comment: is everything running in the same job ?

Comment: i can see lots of related issue on github. was wondering which version of the azure.identity are you using ? before your code run can you try doing an `ac account clear` and add an extra step to re login with `azure/login@v1` ?

Comment: everything runs in the same job (in the same step in fact)
somehow i completely overlooked that its 5 minutes. these tests run for about 2h and i would assume that python sdk is smart enough to request a new token. ie it works fine with TF, but i dont see a AzureFederaedCredential method in azure.identity. i'm using latest azure.identity. also, can you share similar issues on GH, please?

Comment: yeah the sdk is normally smart enough to get  new token

Comment: I've googled `github action  Client assertion is not within its valid time range.` this result was kind of related: https://github.com/Azure/login/issues/372

Comment: this article suggest you can change the token expiration of the `azure/login@v1` action: `token-expiry: 30M` see https://bettersoftwaresuggestions.com/github/github-azure-login-allow-custom-expiry-time-for-oidc-token/

Comment: i dont think thats fair: https://github.com/Azure/login/blob/master/action.yml. and looking at extension code i dont see ability to do that anywhere :(

Comment: oh that does not exists ... sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

the underlying OIDC token issued by Github has only 5 minutes of lifetime hence it doesnt matter if oAuth tokens have 1h lifetime.

my workaround is to refresh Azure Cli auth everytime I need to use it until anything can be done about this (at least I dont see a way to extend token lifetime: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/about-security-hardening-with-openid-connect)

```
def get_azure_credentials():
    token_request = os.environ.get("ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_TOKEN")
    token_uri = os.environ.get("ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL")
    subprocess_helper(f'token=$(curl -H "Authorization: bearer {token_request}" "{token_uri}&audience=api://AzureADTokenExchange" | jq .value -r) && az login --service-principal -u {CLIENT_ID} -t {TENANT_ID} --federated-token $token')
    return AzureCliCredential()
```

ps. subprocess_helper is a wrapper around:

```
subprocess.run(["/bin/sh", "-c", run_me], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

pps. if any1 knows a better solution - I'm up for it